# Memory access violation summing large CSV file into array

Tags: c

My code reads a comma delimited file (CSV) and average numbers into an array. 
It works for number_x_nodes = 1000, however when run for number_x_nodes = 1000 (ie. the whole csv file) it gives a 0xc0000005 exit code. The error occurs in Clion but not Codeblocks.

The CSV file is as follows. The entire file contains 28,325,381 lines and is 1.8GB

```
CoordinateX,CoordinateY,CoordinateZ,Pressure,Temperature,VelocityX,VelocityY,VelocityZ,
0,0,0.0904,33.5797,300,-0.00146382,0.000389435,-0.00147085,
0,0.0003,0.0904,33.5795,300,0.126682,-0.000382509,0.00330599,
0,0.0006,0.0904,33.5793,300,0.250278,-0.00151828,0.0100881,
0,0.0009,0.0904,33.5788,300,0.365407,-0.00287706,0.0184123,
...
after 100 lines, CoordinateZ changes to the next value
after 72 CoordinateZ iterations, CoordinateX changes to the next value
after 3930 CoordinateX iterations, file ends.
```

The code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    /* Open CSV file */
    int BUFFER_SIZE = 128;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    FILE *pFile = fopen("39900.csv","r");
    char *pCell;

    /* Set node counts */
    int number_x_nodes = 3930; //if number_x_nodes = 1000, the code runs as expected
    int number_y_nodes = 100;
    int number_z_nodes = 72;

    /* Setup Array */
    double property_array[number_y_nodes][6]; //property_array[j][n]
    double number_xz_plane_nodes = number_x_nodes*number_z_nodes;
    int n = 0; //property index
    int i = 0; //x-coordinate index
    int j = 0; //y-coordinate index

    /* Initialize entries of array */
    rewind(pFile);
    fgets(buffer,BUFFER_SIZE,pFile);
    for(j=0; j<number_y_nodes; j++) {
        fgets(buffer,BUFFER_SIZE,pFile);
        pCell = strtok(buffer, ",");
        pCell = strtok(NULL, ",");
        property_array[j][0] = strtod(pCell, &pCell);
        pCell = strtok(NULL, ",");
        for (n=1; n<6; n++) {
            pCell = strtok(NULL, ",");
            property_array[j][n] = strtod(pCell, &pCell)/number_xz_plane_nodes;
        }
    }

    /* Average values into the array */
    for (i=0; i<number_xz_plane_nodes; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<number_y_nodes; j++) {
            fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, pFile);
            pCell = strtok(buffer, ",");
            pCell = strtok(NULL, ",");
            pCell = strtok(NULL, ",");
            for (n=1; n<6; n++) {
                pCell = strtok(NULL, ",");
                property_array[j][n] += strtod(pCell, &pCell)/number_xz_plane_nodes; //program crashes on this line
            }
        }
    }

    /* Print array */
    printf("Printing array...\n");
    for(j=0; j<number_y_nodes; j++){
        printf("y_%i = %.7lf --> ",j, property_array[j][0]);
        printf("vel_x = %.30lf\n", property_array[j][3]);
    }

    /* Close file */
    fclose(pFile);

    return(0);
}
```

### Result for int number_x_nodes = 1000

Prints array as expected.

### Result for int number_x_nodes = 3930

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

### Values at crash

buffer = {char [128] of random characters}

number_xy_plane_nodes = 282960

pCell = NULL

n = 1

i = 73799

j = 0

### Editor's Note

The error that lead to this question has been found. Please refer to my answer below.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Maybe you need to provide the full path to the CSV file. What do you get if you add `printf("pFile = %p\n, pFile);` after the call to `fopen`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can confirm I'm accessing the file okay. I added a printf of pFile and received...
pFile = 00007FF94854FA90
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: The error code `0xC0000005` is a windows error and not a compiler related issue. It can be an access violation error, Microsoft error or application fails to start error. Where do you change `int number_x_nodes = 1040;` for the full-file?

Comment: Since I can't duplicate your problem, my best guess is that there is something wrong with your data file. If you are using Visual Studio, my recommendation would be to run your program in the debugger and print the line count after each `fgets`. This would help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited number_x_nodes to equal 3930. It is this value that causes the program to crash. I've ran a debugger. The "buffer" appears to be holding random characters when the program crashes.

Comment: I've looked at the lines of the file where my program crashes and everything looks normal. The CSV file is exported from a commercial software so I trust it would be free of error.

Comment: And _where_ does the program crash, when you reproduce it in the debugger? You should have an exact line and the value of every variable available at that point ...

Comment: I've updated the question with a comment indicating the line where it crashes as well as the variable values at the crash. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the error. The CSV file contains a break 7,380,002 lines in. This is the first thing I checked for when I received the error. I must have checked incorrectly the first time. I would like to thank everyone who commented for their efforts.

```
...
0.65536,0.0686213,0.133,30.3213,300,1.59667,-0.00783055,-0.0092234,
0.65536,0.0705461,0.133,30.1529,300,1.59745,-0.00759862,-0.00799852,
0.65536,0.0725,0.133,29.9784,300,1.59777,-0.00753752,-0.00714456,

0,0,0.0904,33.5797,300,-0.00146382,0.000389435,-0.00147085,
0,0.0003,0.0904,33.5795,300,0.126682,-0.000382509,0.00330599,
0,0.0006,0.0904,33.5793,300,0.250278,-0.00151828,0.0100881,
...
```

Comment: Good for you! Now, you should still copy/paste this information into the bottom of your question, acknowledging that the problem is solved. Why? While this was the problem, it is not an answer that has anything to do with anything wrong in your code. It's just a "God, I hate it when that happens..." type issue. If you have problems making the edit, let me know and I'm happy to do it for you.